# Form Variable determined Dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, coldfusion

**Update**

jsfiddle.net/xDA9p/2 Similiar to this. Except instead of a email or website it would be autodetermining the Image_ID

***Actually if someone could help me by showing me how to merely auto-update the Input form for the Image ID when a certain button is clicked that would be enough to get what I need done. Thanks!***

Currently if you notice the Image_ID has to be put in manually. I am trying to get rid of typing that in so when someone selects an image to look at they can instantly make comments to that image!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>
            Untitled Document
        </title>

        <cfquery datasource="AccessTest" name="qTest">
            SELECT P.Account, P.Image, P.Image_ID, C.Remarks, C.Users, C.Accounts, C.Date_Time
            FROM PictureDB AS P
            INNER JOIN CommentsDB AS C
            ON C.Image_ID = P.Image_ID
            ORDER BY P.Image_ID
        </cfquery>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js">

        </script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                  var images = {
                    <cfoutput query="qTest" group="Image_ID">
                        "#qTest.Image_ID#": {
                            "image": "#qTest.Image#",
                            "remarks": [
                            <cfoutput>
                                "#qTest.Users#, #qTest.Date_Time# <br> #qTest.Remarks# <br> </br>",
                            </cfoutput>
                            ]
                        },
                    </cfoutput>
                };
                  $("button").click(function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var id = $(this).data("id");
                    var src = images[id].image;
                    var desc = images[id].remarks.toString();

                    $("#theImage").attr("src", src).removeClass("hide");
                    $("#theDescription").html(desc).removeClass("hide");
                    });
                });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>



                        <cfoutput query="qTest" group="Account">
                    <button data-id="#qTest.Image_ID#">
                        #qTest.Account#

                    </button>

                </cfoutput> 

                    <cfform name="InsertComments" id="InsertComments">
            <fieldset>
<div id="container">
    <div id="mainContent">


            <textarea name="Remarks" cols="55" rows="4" label="Tour Description"
                                    required="yes" validateat="OnSubmit" message="Please enter your comment here" 
                                    enabled="no">
                        </textarea>
            <input type="text" name="Image_ID" message="Please enter Account Here." 
                                 validateat="onSubmit" required="yes" id="Image_ID" size="10"
                                 maxlength="60">
                        </input>
        <input type="submit" name="insertComments" value="Insert Comments" id="submit">
                        </input>
        </div>
    </div>  
    </fieldset>
    </cfform>
        <cfif IsDefined("form.InsertComments")>

                    <cfquery datasource="AccessTest">
                        INSERT INTO CommentsDB (Remarks, Image_ID, Date_Time )
                        VALUES
                        (<cfqueryparam value="#form.Remarks#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_LONGVARCHAR">

                        , <cfqueryparam value="#form.Image_ID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">

                        , <cfqueryparam value="#now()#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp">

                        )
                    </cfquery>

            </cfif>


                <img id="theImage" class="hide">
        <div id="theDescription" class="hide">
        </div>

        </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Save yourself now.. don't use cflayout, cform, cfinput or any of the other ui tags.

Comment: What would you suggest I use?

Comment: Any other js library / framework that can be updated regularly.

Comment: Use jQuery & the jQuery Validation plugin for form validation, jQuery UI for an accordion if you want specific examples, though there are plenty of other libraries as well.  You are already using jQuery & jQuery UI (from an other question you posted) so just learn to use those and forget about the CF UI crap.

Comment: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2014/01/oi-you-bloody-wankers-stop-using.html

Comment: Reduced the use of CF UI as much as I could.

Comment: I found out I can hardcode , <cfqueryparam value="1" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"> which will make it post into image_id 1 so it has something to do with this. It appears

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xDA9p/2/ Similiar to this. Except instead of a email or website it would be autodetermining the Image_ID

Comment: Would I add something like this? var ID2 = images[id].form.Image_ID;
          $("#theID").html(id2).removeClass("hide");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var text = $( this ).data("id");
$("#Image_ID").val(text);
```

This solved the problem.

Comment: Glad you found an answer, but this same question was already posted multiple times:
[1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21423792/104223)
,[2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418969/using-option-values-jquery)
,[3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414663/j-query-and-forum)
,[4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394338/image-id-determined-by-button-selected) . You should delete the duplicates, so it is only posted once.